# Modifying registry permissions on windows using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, registry

I am modifying the registry permission from within a windows service, basically what i am trying to do is

- Provide read access to Authenticated users.
- Deny write access to Everyone.
- Allow full control to System account and Admin users.

This is my code, can you please review and let me know, if i need to change anything, i wrote a sample application and manually checked the registry permission. Then next time when i run my application, it does not have access to the registry key, not even the read access that i gave to authenticated users.

```
            RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MyCompany\Somekey",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

                    RegistryAccessRule rule1 = new RegistryAccessRule(
                                            new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null),
                                            RegistryRights.ReadKey,
                                            InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                                            PropagationFlags.None,
                                            AccessControlType.Allow);

                    RegistryAccessRule rule2 = new RegistryAccessRule(
                                               new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
                                               RegistryRights.WriteKey,
                                               InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                                               PropagationFlags.None,
                                               AccessControlType.Deny);

                    RegistryAccessRule rule3 = new RegistryAccessRule(
                                               new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null),
                                               RegistryRights.FullControl,
                                               InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                                               PropagationFlags.None,
                                               AccessControlType.Allow);


                    RegistryAccessRule rule4 = new RegistryAccessRule(
                                               new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null),
                                               RegistryRights.FullControl,
                                               InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                                               PropagationFlags.None,
                                               AccessControlType.Allow);


                    RegistrySecurity registrySecurity = regKey.GetAccessControl();

                    registrySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule1);
                    registrySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule2);
                    registrySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule3);
                    registrySecurity.AddAccessRule(rule4);
                    regKey.SetAccessControl(registrySecurity);
```

Comment: Are you closing the registry key after you are finished using it? That could be a possible cause.

Comment: i have wrapped the whole thing in a "Using" statement , still the same issue, any issues in the code.